# Is there a way to bootstrap a Chef node from pure Java implementation?

Tags: java, chef-infra, bootstrapping, knife, jclouds

Typically one bootstraps a Chef node with `boostrap` like so:

```
knife bootstrap mynode.example.com -N mynode -x myuser --sudo --run-list "role[myrole]"
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this from Java without needing Ruby or Chef installed on your OS. For instance, JClouds seems to have a Chef implementation, but I can't tell if it first requires Ruby/Chef installed locally. Ideas?

Comment: I had lots of trouble managing ruby/chef environment stable, if there is Java I would love it

Comment: Install the latest Chef DK (development kit) it will provide the various chef management, commands all using an embedded copy of ruby. This will keep your chef workstation stable. jClouds looks interesting, but I would fear switching because an alternative client would need to work very hard to keep pace with the standard ruby based tools.

Comment: `knife bootstrap` just encapsulates some SSH calls. You can look at the source and replicate it in whichever language you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Everett pointed out, that is exactly what jclouds-chef does. Check out the guide to see how it works.

You don't have to install Ruby/Chef or anything neither locally nor in the machines you are going to bootstrap. The only requirement is that the machine you are going to bootstrap has SSH access enabled and can connect to the Internet. jclouds-chef will connect to it and take care of installing Ruby, Chef, and all the requirements and bootstrap the node, just as knife would do.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what jclouds-chef is for. See the Bootstrap nodes with Chef and the ComputeService section of http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/

Answer (score 0):

There's [this discussion](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2011-08/msg00016.html) about the subject from the Chef mailing list, in which John E. Vincent writes that

> you aren't going to be able to really reimplement chef in Java and
>   running the client on JRuby isn't possible.
>
> You might be able to use jruby and pull in the chef gems for some API
>   interaction if need be.
>
> In the end, Chef is written in ruby. Whatever awkward requirements are
>   going to have to accept that.

And Daniel Cukier responded with:

> I did some tests and it won't be possible to run chef inside the
>   JVM. My only option is to provision the machine using jcloud and then run
>   the bootstrap scripts via ssh.

I'd guess full discussion from the linked thread should provide the details you need. However, as I don't understand much of it myself, I can't really expand on the details.